# How to use an entity inside an architecture in VHDL

Tags: entity, vhdl, fpga, quartus

My purpose is to impement a Keyboard entity which uses Button entites.

So I wrote the following VHDL code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
entity Keyboard is
    port ( ck, stop :       in STD_LOGIC;
             data_in :  in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);
             data_out : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
end Keyboard;

entity Button is
    port ( clk :         in STD_LOGIC ;
             signal_in : in STD_LOGIC;
          output :   out STD_LOGIC);
end Button;

architecture test of Keyboard is
    signal NUM : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0) := (others=>'0');

    component Button is
    port ( clk :         in STD_LOGIC ;
             signal_in : in STD_LOGIC;
          output :   out STD_LOGIC);
    end component;

    begin

    num_0 : entity Button port map(ck,data_in(0),NUM(0));
    num_1 : entity Button port map(ck=>clk,data_in(1)=>signal_in,NUM(1)=>output);
    num_2 : entity Button port map(ck=>clk,data_in(2)=>signal_in,NUM(2)=>output);
    num_3 : entity Button port map(ck=>clk,data_in(3)=>signal_in,NUM(3)=>output);
    num_4 : entity Button port map(ck=>clk,data_in(4)=>signal_in,NUM(4)=>output);
    num_5 : entity Button port map(ck=>clk,data_in(5)=>signal_in,NUM(5)=>output);
    num_6 : entity Button port map(ck=>clk,data_in(6)=>signal_in,NUM(6)=>output);
    num_7 : entity Button port map(ck=>clk,data_in(7)=>signal_in,NUM(7)=>output);
    num_8 : entity Button port map(ck=>clk,data_in(8)=>signal_in,NUM(8)=>output);
    num_9 : entity Button port map(ck=>clk,data_in(9)=>signal_in,NUM(9)=>output);
    num_on : entity Button port map(ck=>clk,data_in(10)=>signal_in,NUM(10)=>output);
    num_off : entity Button port map(ck=>clk,data_in(11)=>signal_in,NUM(11)=>output);

    output <= "0000" when NUM = "000000000001" else --0
                 "0001" when NUM = "000000000010" else --1
                 "0010" when NUM = "000000000100" else --2
                 "0011" when NUM = "000000001000" else --3
                 "0100" when NUM = "000000010000" else --4
                 "0101" when NUM = "000000100000" else --5
                 "0110" when NUM = "000001000000" else --6
                 "0111" when NUM = "000010000000" else --7
                 "1000" when NUM = "000100000000" else --8
                 "1001" when NUM = "001000000000" else --9
                 "1010" when NUM = "010000000000" else --ON
                 "1100" when NUM = "100000000000" else --OFF
                 "1111";

end test;

architecture EdgeDetector of Button is
    signal signal_d:STD_LOGIC;
    begin

    process(clk)
    begin
        if clk= '1' and clk'event then
            signal_d<=signal_in;
      end if;
    end process;

     output<= (not signal_d) and signal_in; 
end EdgeDetector;
```

By starting the compilation on QuartusII I face the following error:

> Error (10482): VHDL error at PitAlarm.vhd(11): object "STD_LOGIC" is
>   used but not declared

But I can't understand what it means with "not declared" ???

Comment: Actuallay I already tried it but with no positive results. I face the same error by using `num_0 : entity Work.Button port map(ck,data_in(0),NUM(0));` and keeping al the rest as my previous post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "direct entity instantiation" you are explicitly binding an entity out of a specific library instead of using "configurations" or some default strategy to find a matching one. So, `num_0 : entity Work.Button port map(...);` - note the explicit library name (here, `Work`).

The specific error you find

> std_logic not declared

comes from the visibility rules for library clauses.

Button's own entity/arch will normally be in a separate file, separately compiled before compiling the top level.

It would then have its own library/use clauses for the library where `std_logic` is declared.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
```

With more than one entity in the same file, this clause only applies to the following entity declaration (and makes it visible o the corresponding architectures).

So you need to repeat these two lines before each entity declaration in the file.

Comment: Before Button and Keyboard were 2 differents vhdl files and I had the same problem. But the solution is what you wrote: I should compile before Button. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Then you would have had a different error, probably `Button` not declared, rather than `std_logic`.